# GRT address vs BTC address

Tags: bitcoin-core

I was asked to provide my BTC addresss and accidentally provided my GRT address to receive funds, the funds were initiated to send, will this be a problem?

Comment: What is a GRT address? It would be helpful if you posted the address, or at least an example of a GRT address that has the same format.

Comment: Is GRT another cryptocurrency based on Bitcoin? If so, there is at least a small chance you might be able to get your GRT private key into your BTC app and use the same address for both. Apart from that small chance - nope! the money was permanently deleted! congratulations!

Comment: Yes, GRT (The Graph) is an Ethereum cryptocurrency. Thank you chytrik and user253751 for responding. I also called Coinbase and the representative told me that it will likely get lost if I tried to send GRT to a BTC wallet but he said I would still be able to see the transaction. Sure, the money is lost in cyberspace, but I could still see it. That's what I was told. Does this make sense? chytrik the wallet address for my GRT is 0x609E0c2B8bb34AbE708201bD106D6E57265e0ce1.

Comment: GRT/Ethereum addresses are nothing like BTC addresses. This doesn't make sense - you can't just send BTC to something that isn't a BTC address.

Comment: Pieter Wuille, that's how I understand it too, but Coinbase said I can still see that someone attempted to send BTC via a GRT/Ehereum address vice versa... they said I can track it/see it but it's not retrievable. Does that make sense? The only reason I keep asking is because I'm second guessing what Coinbase told me. Thanks in advance for input!

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever, unless they're talking about some kind of wrapped BTC on ethereum. In any case, I believe any of that would be off topic here.

Answer (score -2):

Coinbase pools their bitcoin, so the bitcoins you deposit will never be the bitcoin you spend. Bitcoin core does not accept Coinbase transactions. Get a Coinbase wallet, then you can transfer your Coinbase funds to your Coinbase wallet and then to your Bitcoin core wallet.